# Getting error in JMeter while testing with android application

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, android

I have connected mobile phone with my IP config and set port which I have set in JMeter. but while start recording in JMeter and start the application in a phone then it showing an error in JMeter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate so JMeter could decrypt and record HTTPS traffic.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Send it to mobile device vie bluetooth or email or whatever way plays for you
3. Tap on the certificate in email attachment or file manager and follow Android OS instructions to get it installed
4. Remember that the certificate has limited life time so you will have to repeat the procedure each 7 days

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** section of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry for more details.

Also be aware of an alternative solution of recording mobile device traffic, it automates not only certificate installation process, but it's capable of exporting recorded scenarios in "SmartJMX" mode with automated correlation applied, it means that it will generate all the necessary [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to handle dynamic parameters, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more information.